# How do I send a single contact from iPhone using Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, iphone

I have a new car with a Bluetooth Audio System.
I have successfully paired with my iPhone5S, and transferred my contacts.

The Car has a "Vehicle phonebook" which can import selected numbers.
This has a menu to "Import one phonebook entry".
Unfortunately I cannot seem to find any way to send a single contact from the iPhone. (On my old Nokia there was a menu to do this).

Comment: I don't have anyway to test, but if you open `Contacts`, select a contact and scroll down there is a `share contact` link, which allows you to airdrop, message or email the contact.  Does a bluetooth send appear there?

Comment: it was a thought anyway.  It's possible that your phone doesn't support all the same bluthooth profiles that the vehicle does.  [WIkipedia explains Bluetooth profiles reasonably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles).

Comment: @Tyson The manual for the Audio System says the phone must support Object Push Profile (OPP)

Comment: OPP is not supported by apple.  Apple supports these: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3647

Comment: This is a PITA. I bought the iPhone, because my old Nokia did not work well with the Audio System, but my wife's iPhone4 did seem OK.